# Calculate the products of all the combinations in R

Tags: r, list, combinations

List `a` is as follows:

`a<-list(3:6,6:8,3:4,8)`

```
> a
[[1]]
[1] 3 4 5 6

[[2]]
[1] 6 7 8

[[3]]
[1] 3 4

[[4]]
[1] 8
```

My aim is to calculate all the products of all the 2-element combinations in each object. For example, the first object in `a` is `3 4 5 6`, so all the products of the first object is `12 15 18 20 24 30`, and all the products of the second object is `42 48 56`. BUT when there is only one element in the object, the output should be `0`. I planed to solve the problem by using `Map(function(x) combn(x,2,prod),a)`, but it was not suitable when there was only one element in the object (such as the 4th object in `a`).

```
> Map(function(x) combn(x,2,prod),a)
[[1]]
[1] 12 15 18 20 24 30

[[2]]
[1] 42 48 56

[[3]]
[1] 12

[[4]]
 [1]  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  6  8 10 12 14 16 12 15 18 21 24 20 24 28 32 30 35 40 42 48 56
```

So how can I get all the 2-element products of all the combinations in each object  and  get `0` when there is only one element at the same time? Thanks!

My expected result is as follows:

```
[[1]]
[1] 12 15 18 20 24 30

[[2]]
[1] 42 48 56

[[3]]
[1] 12

[[4]]
[1] 0
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use your approach and wrap `combn`:

```
a<-list(3:6,6:8,3:4,8)
combn2 <- function(x, ...) 
  if(length(x) == 1L) 0 else combn(x, ...)
Map(function(x) combn2(x,2,prod),a)
#[[1]]
#[1] 12 15 18 20 24 30
#
#[[2]]
#[1] 42 48 56
#
#[[3]]
#[1] 12
#
#[[4]]
#[1] 0
```

Answer (score 3):

We can try with an `if/else` condition

```
Map(function(x) if(length(x)==1) 0 else combn(x,2, FUN = prod),a)
#[[1]]
#[1] 12 15 18 20 24 30

#[[2]]
#[1] 42 48 56

#[[3]]
#[1] 12

#[[4]]
#[1] 0
```

---

I think @Roland answered it first (9 secs before me, though I didn't see his answer), so a variation of the above is

```
ifelse(lengths(a)==1, 0, Map(function(x) combn(x, 2, prod), a))
```

Or with `lapply`

```
ifelse(lengths(a)==1, 0, lapply(a, function(x) combn(x, 2, FUN = prod)))
```